# How to add workspace libraries to an Eclipse CDT autotools C/C++ project?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt, autotools

I have project `project1` in my *Eclipse CDT* workspace, which produces dynamic libraries I don't want on my system. Then I have `project2` which is an autotools C project that needs the libraries produced by `project1`.

When not an autotools project, it is very easy to add dynamic libraries in the properties of the project. But in the case of an autotools project, the possibilities I have used to using are not available.

Where can I tell it where to find and use the library in the workspace (and of course not the one of the system)?

Answer (score 0):

The following script enables to position some environment variables for the linker:

```
export MYINSTALL=$HOME/somepath
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MYINSTALL/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$MYINSTALL/lib/pkgconfig/:$MYINSTALL/share/pkgconfig/
export PATH=$MYINSTALL/bin:$PATH
export ACLOCAL_PATH=$MYINSTALL/share/aclocal
export ACLOCAL="aclocal -I $ACLOCAL_PATH"
mkdir -p $ACLOCAL_PATH
```

script *myinstallenv*

Both project in the following are built with debug symbols. `project1` is C/C++, `project2` is C only.

`project1` is built with --prefix=$MYINSTALL

```
myinstallenv && CFLAGS="-g -debug -g3 -O0" CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS ./Configure shared linux-elf -Wa,--noexecstack --prefix=$MYINSTALL
```

`project2` with:

```
myinstallenv && CFLAGS="-g -g3 -O0" ./configure --prefix=$MYINSTALL
```

For `project2`, `--prefix=$MYINSTALL` is required only if you want it also installed there and not in the system. Strictly speeking, only `myinstallenv && ./configure` is required.